# Case sensitive and case insenistive search in solr

Tags: solr

I indexed data in solr using following field type configuration. On which I can perform only 
case insensitive search. Eg :If I am typing text:**Abc** or **abc**  is giving same result .

```
 <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

But now my requirement got changed.Suppose If I am searching for Abc then it should give all result matching with Abc not abc,reverse also should work.

Is it possible with current configuration? If not then what configuration should I use.
please suggest me .

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the lowercase filter from your tokenizer and it should solve your problem. Then it will not convert the tokens into lowercase and hence give you the desired results.